# Quotient set and inverse image.

Tags: functional-analysis, quotient-spaces

(What i'm about to say is a subpart of a proof of a theorem).

Let $M, N$ be a closed subspace and a finite dimensional subspace, respectively, of a normed linear space $X$. We define the natural map $A$ from $X$ onto $X/M$ by $Ax = [x]$.

Here the question... i think it is safe to state that $AN = \left\{ n + M \;|\; n \in N\right\}$  but i don't get why $A^{-1} A N = M + N$ ($A^{-1}$ is used in the set theoretic sense).

I mean since $[n] = n + M$ then i would be tempted to say that $AN = N + M$ how could it be the "inverse" be the same?

I mean i understand the meaning by intuition but i don't get the "formal meaning".

Could you help me to have a more thorough look into this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem of notation. I mean $AN$ is in effect a $X/M$ subspace while $ { n+M| n\in N}=N+M$ is a subspace of $X$. So $AN={ n+M| n\in N}$ it's formally uncorrect and you should write $A^{-1}AN={ n+M| n\in N}$.

Comment: Side question: Somebody know how to make braces appear?

Comment: just write. \left\{ \right\}.
However i don't still don't understand (i'm sure however i have a notation problem).

Comment: Ok, thanks. What i meant is that $A: X \mapsto X/M$ so $AM\subset X/M$ while $\left\{ n+M | n\in N \right\}= N+M \subset X$ so they can't be equal. The equality in effect holds for $A^{-1}AN$.

Comment: I'm getting confused, but probably is my fault... $Ax = [x] = x + M$ is correct? so $AN = \left\{ [n] \;|\; n \in N \right\}$ is correct? so... $AN = \left\{ n + M \;|\; n \in N\right\}$ this isn't correct? why? where is the error?

Comment: I don't know if i can give a proper answer but I'll try. You can see it in this way: A is a map that links an element of X to a element of $X/M$ which can be seen as a subset of X. Now $A^{-1}$ is a map that links an element of $X/M$ (a subset of X) to a subset of X and if you see it in this way it's indeed the identity map.